# Laravel Error- The PUT method is not supported for route comments/4/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, routes, methods, put

Trying to update a comment using update function i created but when i route the comment i get the error 'The PUT method is not supported for route comments/4/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.' - the method is called 'POST' and ive called '@method('PUT') - ive cleared out my routes cache using the artisan command and still hasnt fixed it- im new to coding in general and i cant seem to figure out the problem - many thanks

(blade php) edit-comments.blade.php

```
<x-layout>
    <div
    class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-200 p-10 rounded max-w-lg mx-auto mt-24"
    >
    <header class="text-center">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold uppercase mb-1">
            Edit Comment
        </h2>
    </header>

    <form method="POST" action="/comments/{{$comment->id}}/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="mb-6">
            <label
                for="author"
                class="inline-block text-lg mb-2"
                >Name</label
            >
            <input
                type="text"
                class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full"
                name="author"
                value="{{$comment->author}}"
            />

            @error('author')
                <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}} </p>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
            <label for="text" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2"
                >Comment</label
            >
            <input
                type="text"
                class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full"
                name="text"
                value="{{$comment->text}}"
            />

            @error('text')
            <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}} </p>
            @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
            <button
                class="bg-laravel text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black"
            >
                Update Comment
            </button>

            <a href="/" class="text-black ml-4"> Back </a>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </x-layout>
```

CommentsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CommentsRequest;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Photos;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    //Store Comments
    public function store(Photos $photo, CommentsRequest $request):RedirectResponse {
        $data = $request->validated();
        $comment = new Comment();

        $comment->photos_id = $photo->id;
        $comment->author = $data['author'];
        $comment->text = $data['text'];
        $comment->save();

        return back()->with('message', 'Comment uploaded successfully!');
    }

    //Edit Comments form
    public function edit(Comment $comment) {
        return view('edit-comments', ['comment' => $comment]);
    }

    //update Comments
    public function update(Request $request, Comment $comment) {
        $data = $request->validated([
            'author' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required'
        ]);

        $comment->create($data);


        return back()->with('message', 'Comment updated successfully!');
    }

    //Delete Comments
    public function destroy(Comment $comment, Photos $photo):RedirectResponse {
        //if($photo->user_id != auth()->id()) {
        //    abort(403, 'Unauthorised Action');
        //}
        $comment->delete();
        return back()->with('message', 'Comment deleted successfully!');
    }
}
```

Routing that was used

```
//Update comments
Route::put('/comments/{comment}',
[CommentsController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `action` in your `form` tag is different to the `route` that you need. Try removing the `edit` at the end of the `action` path so that it will work.

Tip : To make creating url easier try adding a name to the routes.

```
Route::put('/comments/{comment}',[CommentsController::class, 'update'])
    ->name('comments.update')
    ->middleware('auth');
```

to use it in the form you can just

```
<form action="{{ route('comments.update', ['comment' => $comment->id]) }}">...</form>
```

with this you can ensure that you are using the correct route even if you chage the `path` in the `web.php` in the future.

Comment: i did this and still get the an error 'The PUT method is not supported for route comments/8. Supported methods: POST, DELETE.'  - and thank you for the tips aswell

Answer (score 0):

Your route is invalid. you are trying to access PUT `comments/4/edit` but the there is no such route. Your current route is without `/edit`. so you can change your route to

```
//Update comments
Route::put('/comments/{comment}/edit',
[CommentsController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth');
```

Or you can also change your reference target link int the form to `/comments/{{$comment->id}}` like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="/comments/{{$comment->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: i did this and still get the an error 'The PUT method is not supported for route comments/8. Supported methods: POST, DELETE.'